# NES legend of Zelda fake or real

Tags: the-legend-of-zelda

I recently sold my NES Legend of Zelda that I bought around 1989 for my kids. The buyer thinks it's a fake because it does not have any batch/quality control stamping on the back.  Nothing else about the game looks fake.  Can anyone definitively say that all Zelda NES games produced had a stamp?  And were there even fake copies around in 1989?  I called Nintendo for help, the person I chatted with wasn't even aware that Nintendo's seal was round instead of the oval the first few years. Appreciate any thoughts

Comment: You may be interested in https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/284333/counterfeit-nes-snes-games-how-to-know-if-its-fake

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counterfeit NES/SNES Games-how to know if it's fake?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/284333/counterfeit-nes-snes-games-how-to-know-if-its-fake)