# Is this Astyanax NES cartridge legit?

Tags: nes, astyanax

[image: Astyanax NES cartridge]

I am just looking for anyone who can verify that this NES cartridge is legit and not fake, please. It is of PAL Region, as I am located in Australia.

Comment: Hi Stephan, do you have any reason to assume it isn't?

Comment: Not really. Im pretty sure its real legit copy but just wanted extra verification from someone else.

Comment: Related: [Counterfeit NES/SNES Games-how to know if it's fake?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/284333/4797)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this website](https://www.pricecharting.com/game/nes/astyanax) the circuit board should look like this

[image: Astyanax NES circuit board]

That looks right to my untrained eye.  Of course it's possible to fake the chips and traces, but I don't know why someone would go through the effort for a game that's currently selling for $50.

If you want a more detailed validation, you'll need to take it to a professional.

Comment: The circuit you showed is the USA NTSC region, where as mine is AUS PAL region.

Comment: Which is presumablly why the PRG rom chip on yours is labeled "PAL-YX-0 PRG" instead of "NES-YX-0-PRG".

Comment: Yes thats right.

Comment: @Stephan: That doesn't seem relevant since they're nearly identical anyways. The point is that a cheap fake would have something like a Raspberry Pi or Arduino board, which would look completely different.

Comment: An RPI or arduino seems unlikely. Still I suspect most fakes at least for cheaper games would look obviously different at the PCB level.

Comment: Sure someone could potentially salvage a CIC and MMC from a cheaper game, and then somehow disguise thier proms to look like the original mask-roms but it would seem like a lot of effort to go to unless the game was super-valuable.

Comment: So based on what you saying, does that then mean that the Asyanax pcb board is 100% real and orignal? Thats what i wanted to find out. Thanks